# Customize Control Template Avalonia

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

Simple question: how to change the standart control template in Avalonia, e.g. visual effect when Click to control.

I tried to find a standard template to change it like WPF, but I didn't find any information about it.

Comment: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/styling/styles#pseudoclasses